# Discord.py Рандом с минимальным и максимальным числом, указывается автором

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

Помогите пожалуйста с командой. Суть команды - вывести рандомное число, но рамки минимального и максимального числа в рандоме должны указываться человеком, который вызвал команду.

Прикреплю свою попытку разобраться в рандом:

```
@bot.command()
async def roll(ctx, *, arg1,):  #пофиксить
    embed = discord.Embed(
    title = 'Ваше случайное число:',
    description = (random.choice(arg1)),
    colour=discord.Colour.dark_purple()
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Откройте раздел "[**Работа с аргументами команды**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B)" и по аналогии укажите 2 аргумента-числа — нижняя граница `random.randint()` и верхняя

Comment: @denisnumb, спасибо за наводку. Все таки random.Choise тут не совсем подходило и аргументы фигово были указаны:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначало импортируйте библиотеку random, а после попробуйте этот код:

```
@bot.command()
async def rand(mes,amount1=0,amount2=100): #amount1=минимальное,amount2=максимальное , значения после переменных - то, что будет приниматься по стандарту, если человек не указал минимальное и максимальное при вводе команды.
    await mes.reply(random.randint(amount1, amount2))
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, смог заметить свою ошибку